# The requested package symfony/assetic-bundle could not be found in any version

Tags: php, bundle, composer-php, symfony-2.2

I'm trying to update Symfony2 from 2.0 to 2.2 (2.2 version is mandatory) but composer install command results in the following error:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/assetic-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for pinroom/pinroom-web 2.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by pinroom/pinroom-web[2.2.x-dev].
    - pinroom/pinroom-web 2.2.x-dev requires symfony/assetic-bundle 2.3.*@dev -> no matching package found.
```

The composer.json contents:

```
{
    "name": "pinroom/pinroom-web",
    "description": "Pinroom symfony2 web application",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "predis/predis": "0.*",
        "snc/redis-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
        "cybernox/amazon-webservices-bundle": ">=1.5.4",
        "gregwar/image-bundle": "dev-master",
        "oldsound/rabbitmq-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle": "1.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

If I change symfony/assetic-bundle version to "2.1.*", composer install works but install assets fail with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655664/symfony-2-assetic-fatal-error-class-assetic-util-pathutils-not-found-on-asset) error. I've tried proposed solution in related post but it cause the composer error.

Anyone passed this?

Thanks in advance & sorry for my english.

**EDIT**

It was by dependencies errors. Finally I'm inmersed in 2.2 - 2.3LTS upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably only update to the latest, which is 2.4 or 2.5, its not usually recommended to install an older version.  This is up to you.  I can only include the changes which i see on my composer.json file which you might want to try.

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/"}
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.*",
    "jquery/jquery":  "1.10.*",
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "@stable",
    "symfony/icu": "1.1.*",
    "rhumsaa/array_column": "~1.1",
    "webfactory/exceptions-bundle": "@stable"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",

        "Braincrafted\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::install"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",

        "Braincrafted\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::install"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    },

    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
},

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jquery/jquery",
            "version": "1.10.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js",
                "type": "file"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

If you notice a few things you might want to check and try the following:

1) the name:, i dont know what this is for, but it may be causing the "pinroom" problem.

```
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
```

2) the symfony version `"symfony/symfony": "~2.4",1`

3) the version your indicating for assetic bundle `"symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",`

4) the minimum stability specified `"minimum-stability": "stable",`